# Need to jump from panel 6 to panel 9 directly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

I am using  9 panels in my c# gui  code and 
when i click a button I need to jump from panel6 to panel 9 in my gui.
I tried

```
panel7.visible = false;
panel8.visible = false;
panel9.visible = true;
```

but dint work.
Its working only when i want to go to the next panel.
any method ??

Comment: We need more, and first of all, working code. What technology are you using? Windows Forms, Web Forms, etc.?

Comment: I am using windows form

Comment: What do you mean by "jump"?

Comment: Guessing you also want `panel6.visible = false;`?

Comment: i mean I have a button "NEXT" . Instead of going to the next panel when i press it , i want to go to the next next panel

Comment: @Belogix i tried it . when i execute its going to form1 not panel 9

Comment: You need to use the [Control.OnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the panel(s) in question.

Comment: Is Panel9 visible though? You may want to set focus to a control on Panel9? Say you have a textbox you could do `TextBox1.Focus();` - Also, a screenshot or expand your question to explain more about what you are getting and what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [BringToFront](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
panel9.BringToFront();
```

`panel9` may be visible but another visible control may be stacked over it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys i got it :)
we have to make the visibility of all the panels which comes after it to true.
If i want to shift from panel 6 to panel 9 then

```
panel7.visible=true;
panel8.visible=true;
panel9.visible=true;
```